# AUC and accuracy interpretation

Tags: accuracy, auc

An  accuracy $80\%$  of a model that predicts binary outcomes is interpreted  as: 
Given a sample whose outcomes we want to predict, 80% of the prediction will be correct.

What does an AUC of $80\%$ mean?  I just want to know how people think about this interpretation

Comment: An AUC of 0.8 means that your model can successfully discriminate 80 % of your data based on a given threshold.

Comment: I think your interpretation boils down to the accuracy.